# Passing a new function to a osascript command

Tags: macos, osascript

I have function to change the title of a terminal. I wish to pass this to a osascript command.

I try:

```
function title {
  name=hostname
  printf "\033]0;$name %s\007" "$1"
}

osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"" \
    -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"t\" using {command down}" \
    -e "do script \"title newTitle \" in front window" \
    -e "end tell"
    > /dev/null;
```

It does not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is your function defined in your `.bash_profile`? 
If so, this should work (below). If not, you need to add it, or else the new tab you create doesn't know about the function.

Multi-line scripts without `$1` substitution can be put inside single quotes without escaping...

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "title NewTitle" in front window
end tell'
```

The `> /dev/null` doesn't seem to make much difference because of the text that is generated while launching the new tab.